# How to set field as hidden in list content type using API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, sharepoint-rest-api, column

I need to set field as hidden (not visible on list form) using REST API. I don't know how to setup command.

I found location of this parameter in xml but I don't know how to refer and update them, you can see on screenshots Hidden="TRUE" in <d:Schemaxml> - by default it is "FALSE" - how to update it?

[image: hidden]

[image: schema]

[image: hidden]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using REST API, suggest you use CSOM to hide a list content type field.

The demo code for your reference:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
 
#function to Hide Column From List Content Type in SharePoint Online
Function Hide-ColumnFromContentType()
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $ListName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $ContentTypeName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $ColumnName
    )
 
    Try {
        $Cred= Get-Credential
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
 
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
         
        #Get the List
        $List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
        $Ctx.Load($List)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
        #Get the content type
        $ContentTypes = $List.ContentTypes
        $Ctx.Load($ContentTypes)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        $ContentType = $ContentTypes | Where {$_.Name -eq $ContentTypeName}
 
        #Get the Field link from content type
        $FieldLinks =$ContentType.FieldLinks
        $Ctx.Load($FieldLinks)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        $FieldLink = $FieldLinks | Where {$_.Name -eq $ColumnName}
 
        #Hide the Field link
        $FieldLink.Hidden = $True
         
        #Update Content type
        $ContentType.update($False)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
        Write-host "Column Hidden from the Content Type Successfully!" -ForegroundColor Green 
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Hiding Column in Content Type!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
 
#Set parameter values
$SiteURL="https://crescent.sharepoint.com"
$ListName="Projects"
$ContentTypeName="Item"
$ColumnName="Priority"
 
#Call the function
Hide-ColumnFromContentType -SiteURL $SiteURL -ListName $ListName -ContentTypeName $ContentTypeName -ColumnName $ColumnName
```

More information, please refer to the [blog](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/01/sharepoint-online-hide-column-from-content-type-using-powershell.html).